# discordjs Embed won't show up

Tags: discord.js, embed, twitch-api

Ok, so i'm trying to make a push notification for my discord.

i found this script online.

but it will not post the embed....

This is my monitor code:

```
TwitchMonitor.onChannelLiveUpdate((streamData) => {
    const isLive = streamData.type === "live";

    // Refresh channel list
    try {
        syncServerList(false);
    } catch (e) { }

    // Update activity
    StreamActivity.setChannelOnline(streamData);

    // Generate message
    const msgFormatted = `${streamData.user_name} is nu live op twitch <:bday:967848861613826108> kom je ook?`;
    const msgEmbed = LiveEmbed.createForStream(streamData);

    // Broadcast to all target channels
    let anySent = false;

    for (let i = 0; i < targetChannels.length; i++) {
        const discordChannel = targetChannels[i];
        const liveMsgDiscrim = `${discordChannel.guild.id}_${discordChannel.name}_${streamData.id}`;

        if (discordChannel) {
            try {
                // Either send a new message, or update an old one
                let existingMsgId = messageHistory[liveMsgDiscrim] || null;

                if (existingMsgId) {
                    // Fetch existing message
                    discordChannel.messages.fetch(existingMsgId)
                      .then((existingMsg) => {
                        existingMsg.edit(msgFormatted, {
                          embed: msgEmbed
                        }).then((message) => {
                          // Clean up entry if no longer live
                          if (!isLive) {
                            delete messageHistory[liveMsgDiscrim];
                            liveMessageDb.put('history', messageHistory);
                          }
                        });
                      })
                      .catch((e) => {
                        // Unable to retrieve message object for editing
                        if (e.message === "Unknown Message") {
                            // Specific error: the message does not exist, most likely deleted.
                            delete messageHistory[liveMsgDiscrim];
                            liveMessageDb.put('history', messageHistory);
                            // This will cause the message to be posted as new in the next update if needed.
                        }
                      });
                } else {
                    // Sending a new message
                    if (!isLive) {
                        // We do not post "new" notifications for channels going/being offline
                        continue;
                    }

                    // Expand the message with a @mention for "here" or "everyone"
                    // We don't do this in updates because it causes some people to get spammed
                    let mentionMode = (config.discord_mentions && config.discord_mentions[streamData.user_name.toLowerCase()]) || null;

                    if (mentionMode) {
                        mentionMode = mentionMode.toLowerCase();

                        if (mentionMode === "Nu-Live") {
                            // Reserved @ keywords for discord that can be mentioned directly as text
                            mentionMode = `@${mentionMode}`;
                        } else {
                            // Most likely a role that needs to be translated to <@&id> format
                            let roleData = discordChannel.guild.roles.cache.find((role) => {
                                return (role.name.toLowerCase() === mentionMode);
                            });

                            if (roleData) {
                                mentionMode = `<@&${roleData.id}>`;
                            } else {
                                console.log('[Discord]', `Cannot mention role: ${mentionMode}`,
                                  `(does not exist on server ${discordChannel.guild.name})`);
                                mentionMode = null;
                            }
                        }
                    }

                    let msgToSend = msgFormatted;

                    if (mentionMode) {
                        msgToSend = msgFormatted + ` ${mentionMode}`
                    }

                    let msgOptions = {
                        embed: msgEmbed
                    };

                    discordChannel.send(msgToSend, msgOptions)
                        .then((message) => {
                            console.log('[Discord]', `Sent announce msg to #${discordChannel.name} on ${discordChannel.guild.name}`)

                            messageHistory[liveMsgDiscrim] = message.id;
                            liveMessageDb.put('history', messageHistory);
                        })
                        .catch((err) => {
                            console.log('[Discord]', `Could not send announce msg to #${discordChannel.name} on ${discordChannel.guild.name}:`, err.message);
                        });
                }

                anySent = true;
            } catch (e) {
                console.warn('[Discord]', 'Message send problem:', e);
            }
        }
    }

    liveMessageDb.put('history', messageHistory);
    return anySent;
});
```

This is the embed code:

```
const Discord = require('discord.js');
const moment = require('moment');
const humanizeDuration = require("humanize-duration");
const config = require('../data/config.json');

class LiveEmbed {
  static createForStream(streamData) {
    const isLive = streamData.type === "live";
    const allowBoxArt = config.twitch_use_boxart;

    let msgEmbed = new Discord.MessageEmbed();
    msgEmbed.setColor(isLive ? "RED" : "BLACK");
    msgEmbed.setURL(`https://twitch.tv/${(streamData.login || streamData.user_name).toLowerCase()}`);

    // Thumbnail
    let thumbUrl = streamData.profile_image_url;

    if (allowBoxArt && streamData.game && streamData.game.box_art_url) {
      thumbUrl = streamData.game.box_art_url;
      thumbUrl = thumbUrl.replace("{width}", "288");
      thumbUrl = thumbUrl.replace("{height}", "384");
    }

    msgEmbed.setThumbnail(thumbUrl);

    if (isLive) {
      // Title
      msgEmbed.setTitle(`:red_circle: **${streamData.user_name} is live op Twitch!**`);
      msgEmbed.addField("Title", streamData.title, false);
    } else {
      msgEmbed.setTitle(`:white_circle: ${streamData.user_name} was live op Twitch.`);
      msgEmbed.setDescription('The stream has now ended.');

      msgEmbed.addField("Title", streamData.title, true);
    }

    // Add game
    if (streamData.game) {
      msgEmbed.addField("Game", streamData.game.name, false);
    }

    if (isLive) {
      // Add status
      msgEmbed.addField("Status", isLive ? `Live with ${streamData.viewer_count} viewers` : 'Stream has ended', true);

      // Set main image (stream preview)
      let imageUrl = streamData.thumbnail_url;
      imageUrl = imageUrl.replace("{width}", "1280");
      imageUrl = imageUrl.replace("{height}", "720");
      let thumbnailBuster = (Date.now() / 1000).toFixed(0);
      imageUrl += `?t=${thumbnailBuster}`;
      msgEmbed.setImage(imageUrl);

      // Add uptime
      let now = moment();
      let startedAt = moment(streamData.started_at);

      msgEmbed.addField("Uptime", humanizeDuration(now - startedAt, {
        delimiter: ", ",
        largest: 2,
        round: true,
        units: ["y", "mo", "w", "d", "h", "m"]
      }), true);
    }

    return msgEmbed;
  }
}

module.exports = LiveEmbed;
```

But it won't post the embed, only the msg. as you can see it updates teh msg aswell.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ddiSW.jpg)

i'm stuck on this for four days now, can someone help?

Comment: try putting `msgEmbed` in brackets like this `embed: [msgEmbed]`

Comment: it's `{embeds: [msgEmbed]}` in the `.send()` brackets.

Comment: @panzer-chan
It still won't post an embed :D

Comment: Could it be becouse the embed is called from an other file? it did work in discordjs 12... and now that i'm using v13 it doesn't work

Comment: i found out what was going wrong
needed to change the way the msg was sent!

i changed it to:

`message.channel.send({
  content: 'Input',
  embeds: [Input],
});`